# tkinter image display shows TclError error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to simply display a logo or image in my GUI. I tried different techniques as posted on the internet, however all seems to give me an error as `TclError: image "pyimage27" doesn't exist`. I have checked the file is correct(png file) and the path too. I still cant display the image. Below is my simple code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def show_image():
    img_label = tk.Label(root)
    img_label.image = tk.PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
    img_label['image'] = img_label.image

    img_label.pack()


show_image()
root.mainloop()
```

Error that i get

```
  File "C:\Users\bb\Documents
\line.py", line 54, in <module>
    alien()

  File "C:\Users\bb\Documents
\test.py\line.py", line 26, in __init__
    self.alien2 = self.canvas.create_image((100,100),image=CardVar,anchor=CENTER)

  File "C:\Users\bb\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2489, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)

  File "C:\Users\bb\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2480, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))

TclError: image "pyimage30" doesn't exist
```

Thank you

Many similar answers are available but that did not help :

1. [When using Tkinter, error: TclError: image "pyimage8" doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012062/when-using-tkinter-error-tclerror-image-pyimage8-doesnt-exist)
2. [Python: Tkinter TclError: can't invoke "image" command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986128/python-tkinter-tclerror-cant-invoke-image-command)

Comment: Does your simplified code actual generate the error when you run it?  I suspect that your real code has more than one call to `Tk()`, this is one of the numerous problems that can result from that.

Comment: The error shown is from `create_image()` but your code does not have such statement.

Comment: Yes , u r right. My main code has more calls to Tk() and it gives me the error. what is the solution?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should only call `Tk()` once. To avoid that depends only exactly what you're trying to do (which we can't tell from the sample code in your question).

Comment: You have to use `Toplevel()` to create additional windows.  `Tk()` does much more than create a window - it creates the entire Tcl/Tk environment that implements the GUI, the window is just an unavoidable side-effect.  If you call it more than once, you can have situations such as an image existing in one of the environments, and a widget wanting to use that image existing in another environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `PhotoImage(file="path", master=root)`